# Unable to access modem IP through Linksys EA2700 router

Tags: router, modem

Router IP: 192.168.1.1 (Linksys EA2700)
Modem IP: 192.168.100.1 (Technicolor TC4350)

Everything here refers to a wired configuration.

Entering the modem IP in a browser address bar returns an ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT, but the title bar shows: "http://192.168.100.1/cgi-bin/docsis_stats.cgi".

Trying to re-enter the modem IP in the address bar shows the pre-filled text: "192.168.100.1 Page Redirection", and will produce the same results.

If I run the ethernet cable directly from the PC to the modem, I can connect easily and as advertised.

How can I connect to my modem without removing my router or having it "protect me" from the modem?

Comment: Is there a Unix or Linux system in here somewhere, or is this a networking problem?

Comment: Probably the latter, but I am doing this from an Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: Why is your Router in a different Network than your modem?  Both are class C, but you have NAT occuring twice.  Either put the cable modem in the same IP range as the router or, but the router into Bridging mode, so that it accepts an IP from the modem.  See my answer below.

Comment: @eyoung100 modem IP isn't configurable - All DOCSIS modems MUST respond to the diagnostic address `192.168.100.1` on the internal interface. It's written into the DOCSIS spec.

Comment: @KentC does the modem work at all when you have it connected to your router (i.e. can you reach the internet)? Also, be sue to always reboot the modem whenever you switch which device is connected to it. They generally only permit a single client device to be bridged, and a reboot is needed to refresh that entry.

Comment: 192.168.100.1 is not configurable. I suggest reading the DOCSIS specification. It makes it very clear.

Comment: The DOCSIS specification is irrelevant. The cable modem is properly converting the data from the cable to the ethernet cable required by the router. This is connected to the "internet" side of the router, which then routes the traffic to the various wired ports. This is all working as it should. The problem is the router is redirecting requests to see the modem that have been made by anything "inside" the router (the local network?). The modems' IP is in the 192.168.x.x range, so why is the router redirecting it and how can I connect to the modem from behind the router?

Comment: As per my answer and @guzzijason comments, 192.168.100.1 is a special fake address and the modem is not in the 192.168.x.x range. The sooner you understand that, or stop ignoring what we are trying to tell you, the sooner you might understand why you might be having difficulties dealing with that address behind a router. The DOCSIS specification for worse or better defines and documents the cable modem behaviour and the HFC infra-structure behaviour very extensively, from TCP/UDP, configuration files to the electrical signal levels. I am afraid it is quite relevant for what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: You cannot access 192.168.100.1 by *design* when not directly connected via a local link/cable. It is a special fake IP address meant for ISP maintainers/operators.

Not being able to routing it from the Internet/customer side, can be construed as much as a security, and mainly as the simplicity of the 192.168.0.1 simple implementation in firmware, depeding on the CM make and model. (e.g. the link local-only access to 192.168.100.1 feature is there *by design*)

**Long answer**:

Besides you mentioning a modem per itself, what gives away that you are using a DOCSIS cable modem (the Technicolor TC4350) is the URL of the title bar.

Now that we know we are talking about a DOCSIS cable modem, having managing a cable ISP in the past, I can tell you that 192.168.100.1 is a *virtual IP address* of your CM (or of most modern DOCSIS cable modems), meant for diagnostics purposes, and the CM is not in the 192.168.x.x range.

From [DOCSIS 3.0 Specifications](https://www.cablelabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/CM-SP-OSSIv3.0-I05-071206.pdf)

> The CM MUST support 192.168.100.1, as the well
>   -known diagnostic IP address a ccessible only from the CMCI  interfaces.   The CM MUST support the well
>   -known diagnostic IP address, 192.168.100.1, on all physical  interfaces associated with the CMCI.   The CM MUST drop SNMP requests
>   coming from the CATV interface  targeting the well- known  IP address

192.168.100.1 is not the "real" address of your CM. See image down bellow from an OSX app [cablemdiag](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/31493/cablemdiag), that I developed, to understand the bit about a different address.

The cable interface will have a different IP address from the provider infra-structure, often in the 10.x.x.x/x range, that usually does not change over time *unless there are big changes in the ISP or you change your modem, and even then often the address is tied to a customer. That CM is a bridge. Modern configurations also can couple the CM together with a router internally.

Nonetheless, as mentioned before, that 192.168.100.1 is a virtual address, that is emulated at the local link level, in the ethernet interface of a cable modem. Captured/intercepted packets meant for 192.168.100.1 have then an answer.

As far as I am aware, that address is not supposed to be talked to from other networks, so you cannot access it on your Linux behind a router connected to your CM; as you found out, you have got to have the Ubuntu machine directly connected to your cable modem, and there is (no simple) way around it.

This is an actual image from my parents' cable modem. While this modem answers to 192.168.100 for diagnostic purposes since booting, the CM address is in reality 10.200.26.29/18 after getting an IP address from the provider.

You might however, depending on how much your ISP protects the cable modem, try to find out the real broadband address of your CM via SNMP (as in the picture). Mind you this is not guaranteed to work. You can try to find a program to do that, or try in Linux *when connected directly via a cable to the cable modem*:

Getting HFC IP address:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c public 192.168.100.1 1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.1.0
```

Getting HFC netmask:

```
snmpwak -v2c -c public 192.168.100.1 1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.3.0
```

You might also simply ask your ISP about your HFC/cable modem IP address, though I doubt in bigger ISPs you will be told your HFC CM IP address.

Once again, if you do indeed find the broadband ISP CM address, what you can do with it depends on the CM make and model, and how much your ISP protects the modem.

[image: cm]